# NestJS - ConfigService GET method is undefined when called within onModuleInit()

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, nestjs, lifecycle

I'm trying to setup a transporter in the NestJS lifecylce method `onModuleInit()` with the npm library "Nodemailer". So that I can easily send emails from other services in my backend, but I'm getting an error that says the `get` method is undefined on `configService`. Bear in mind I can successfully retrieve my environment variables from other methods within my `MailService` class, it's just the `onModuleInit()` that's cause for grief. Is there some OOP principle that I'm not privy to which is my cause for issue? Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

**CODE**

```
import { OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import SMTPTransport from 'nodemailer/lib/smtp-transport';

interface EnvironmentVariables {
  MAIL_USER: string;
  MAIL_PASS: string;
}

export class MailService implements OnModuleInit {
  transporter: nodemailer.Transporter<SMTPTransport.SentMessageInfo>;
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService<EnvironmentVariables>) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
      {
        host: 'smtp.office365.com',
        secure: false,
        tls: {
          ciphers: 'SSLv3',
        },
        auth: {
          user: this.configService.get('MAIL_USER', { infer: true }),
          pass: this.configService.get('MAIL_PASS', { infer: true }),
        },
        logger: true,
        allowInternalNetworkInterfaces: false,
      })
   }
```

**ERROR**

```
user: this.configService.get('MAIL_USER', { infer: true }),
                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

I was able to successfully retrieve environment variables with the `get` method in other methods that I had defined within the `MailService` class that I had created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `@Injectable()` decorator on your class. That decorator forces Typescript to emit metadata about the constructor so Nest knows what parameters to pass where

Comment: That was it thanks! Can't believe it was such a simple issue. 